# How to filter an R data.table by index and condition

Tags: r, data.table

Please have a look at the following sample code.

```
DT <-data.table(1:15,0,rbinom(15,2,0.5))
```

I can filter by condition `DT[V3 == 1,]` or select rows by index `DT[1:5,]`.

How can I do both? In the following code, the sequence of the indexed rows seems to by ignored:

```
DT[V3 == 1 & 1:5]
```

I could do `DT[1:5,][V3 == 1]`, but then, for example, I wouldn't be able to modify the filtered rows:

```
DT[1:5,][V3 == 1, V2 := 1]
```

This only works with the following workaround:

```
DT[V3 == 1 & DT[,.I <= 5], V2 := 1]
```

However, this looks too data.frame-ish to me. Is there a more elegant way and why does `DT[V3 == 1 & 1:5]` not work?

Comment: `&` combines two logical vectors. `1:5` is an integer vector. I don't know why you would expect this to work. Your workaround looks alright to me. What is your specific problem with your solution to an unusual problem?

Comment: We could try ` DT[V3==1 & 1:.N %in% 1:5]`

Comment: For modifying the filtered rows will `DT[1:5][V3==1, "V2"] <- 1` work?

Comment: @Roland: Of course,  `&` on integer vector doesn't make sense. Maybe I was just fooled by the fact that if expression, which filter rows and look syntactically similar can be combined. Maybe by internally transforming an integer vector to a logical... My problems is as described. Modify the first rows of a column based on a condition.

Comment: @BrandenMurray That would copy the whole data.table, which is not something you want with data of decent size.

Comment: @akrun: Thanks. I'd like this more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a faster way for @akrun's example:

```
set.seed(24)
DT <- data.table(1:1e6, 0, rbinom(1e6, 2, 0.5))
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( 
    DT1[which(V3[1:5]==1L), V2:= 1], 
    DT2[intersect(which(V3==1), 1:5), V2 := 1]
, times = 1, unit = "relative" )

# Unit: relative
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  sequential  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000     1
#     set_ops 55.43582 55.43582 55.43582 55.43582 55.43582 55.43582     1
```

It's "sequential" in the sense that we subset by index before evaluating the condition.

The generalization is

```
cond = quote(V3 == 1)
indx = 1:5

DT[ DT[indx, indx[eval(cond)]], V2 := 1]
# or
set(DT, i = DT[indx, indx[eval(cond)]], j = "V2", v = 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

We can try

```
DT[V3==1 & 1:.N %in% 1:5,  V2 := 1]
```

Or another option is

```
DT[intersect(which(V3==1), 1:5), V2 := 1]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
DT <- data.table(1:1e6, 0, rbinom(1e6, 2, 0.5))
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
```

OP's version

```
system.time({
 DT[V3 == 1 & DT[,.I <= 5], V2:= 1] 
})
#user  system elapsed 
#0.08    0.00    0.08
```

Modified options

```
system.time({
 DT1[V3==1 & 1:.N %in% 1:5,  V2 := 1]
})
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.14    0.00    0.14 

system.time({
  DT2[intersect(which(V3==1), 1:5), V2 := 1]
})
 # user  system elapsed 
 #  0.05    0.00    0.05
```

Comment: I've benchmarked now with a one million rows data.table. Your first solution tends to be slower by a few milliseconds on my system. Your second solution is faster. +1

Comment: @Roland You are right.  I thought the `[.data.table` makes a lot of difference.  I was wrong.